# How can I ignore a condition on entity framework query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to make a query using entity framework with some restrictions. The issue is that sometimes there are no restrictions, so I don´t know if what I doing is the best practice.

My EF code is as:

```
Get(x => x.CreationDate >= filterInit 
      && x.CreationDate <= filterEnd 
      && x.Cond1 > ax 
      && x.Cond2 > y).ToListAsync();
```

If ax is, for example, null, I do this:

```
if(ax == null){
     Get(x => x.CreationDate >= filterInit 
      && x.CreationDate <= filterEnd  
      && x.Cond2 > y).ToListAsync();   
}else if(y == null)
{ 
Get(x => x.CreationDate >= filterInit 
      && x.CreationDate <= filterEnd 
      && x.Cond1 > ax ).ToListAsync();  
}else{
Get(x => x.CreationDate >= filterInit 
 && x.CreationDate <= filterEnd 
 && x.Cond1 > ax 
 && x.Cond2 > y).ToListAsync();   
}
```

I´m sure that there is a pretty way to do this, but I dont know how.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Maybe this help https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232814-compare-nulls-in-database-as-in-c-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 6):

The normal idiom for this is

```
IQueryable<SomeEntity> q = ...;
if (ax != null)
{
  q = q.Where(x => x.Cond1 == ax);
}
if (y != null)
{
  q = q.Where(x => x.Cond2 == y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for null variable values within the query and use them if not null:

```
Get(x => x.CreationDate >= filterInit 
    && x.CreationDate <= filterEnd 
    && (ax == null || x.Cond1 > ax)
    && (y == null || x.Cond2 > y))
    .ToListAsync();
```